# Fast add huge HashSet<string> to ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox, hashset

Hellow! How can I add huge (~2000000 records) **HashSet** to **ListBox**? I have used **foreach** and inside **listBox1.Add(...)**, but it is slow. I thinck that I'm to use **AddRange(...)**, but I can't do that becouse I do not know how to convert **HashSet** to **object[]**.

May be you know another way to fast load hashset to listbox?

Comment: Why speed of adding 2m items to list box matters when you will not be able to use it afterwards anyway?

Comment: See first two dupes for direct answer to your question (e.g. call `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()`). See `Enumerable.ToArray()` extension method to convert your set to an array. See third dupe for the best advice, which is to not expect your users to be able to navigate a `ListBox` with 2 million items in it in the first place.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov im text using filters via TextBox